# How to map EF object through mapping table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, ef-code-first-mapping

I have two database tables -- Customer_Values and Customer_Attributes... and it's... dumb.  Terrible.

Customer_Values has things like

```
CustomerId | AttributeId | Value
--------------------------------
        01 |          01 | Steve
        02 |          01 | Frank
        01 |          02 | Smith 

etc...
```

And Customer_Attributes looks like this

```
AttributeId |      Value
------------------------
         01 | First Name
         02 |  Last Name
```

I would like to map the first table into an Entity object like this...

```cs
class {
   string FirstName { get; set; }
   string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

But I'm not at all sure at all how to do that.

I'm using EF 6, code-first

Comment: Any particular reason that you want to map them to an entity object together instead of mapping to objects as two separate entities and then using LINQ/EF Core to do your join afterwards?

Comment: @SamMullinix -- Only because there will never be an instance where I want to pull from the values table without filtering by `AttributeId`.  I'd rather do all of that up front, for ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your context could be as follows (notice the FK reference, we can se the model up to enable the reference of the FK via Customer_Values):

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer_Values> Customer_Value { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer_Attributes> Customer_Attribute { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer_Attributes>()
            .HasOne(v => v.Customer_Values)
            .WithOne(a => a.Customer_Attributes)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.AttributeId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Constraint_Name_Here");
    }
}
```

Customer Values reference to Customer Attributes:

```
public class Customer_Values
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public <Customer_Attributes> Customer_Attribute { get; set; }
}
```

Customer Attributes picks up the Customer ID via 1:1 relationship

```
public class Customer_Attributes
{
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

Hopefully this gives you the right idea!

[Microsoft Doc FK Modeling Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/fk-constraints)